# Change abstract page position to top in report format

Tags: vertical-alignment, abstract

My document type should be `report` and I need to start my abstract at the top of the page. But with the below code, the abstract is centered on the page. What do I need to do? (I cannot change the type of document.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
.................
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `titlepage` class option (which is the default in `report`), the start of the `abstract` environment contains `\null\vfil` which (together with a corresponding `\vfil\null` at the end) vertically centers the environment. Remove `\null\vfil`, e.g. with the help of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```